# Column Space matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is the column space of A not the same as the column space of the row echelon of A?

Answer (score 1):

The column space of the row echelon form of $A$ is the column space of $LA$, where $L$ is the matrix that transforms $A$ into row echelon form.  So the column space of $A$ is transformed by $L$ to get the column space of the row echelon form of $A$.

If $A$ is square and invertible, these spaces will be the same (since the column spaces are each a basis for the whole space).  But recall that you can do row reduction even for non-invertible matrices, so $L$ may transform the column space of $A$ to a different subspace.

For example, matrix
$$ A = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 &  2 \end{matrix}\right] $$
has column space spanned by vector $(1,1)$.
The row echelon form of $A$ is
$$ LA = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 &  0 \end{matrix}\right] $$
where
$$ L = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ -1 &  1 \end{matrix}\right] $$
and $LA$ has column space spanned by $(1,0)$.